# Is there a function to remove an element from a vector without shifting it in the c++ stdlib?

Tags: c++, vector, std

If I use `vector.erase()` such as

```
std::vector<int> n = { 3, 5, 6, 7 };
n.erase(n.begin() + 1);
```

`vector` will shift all the elements after the element removed down.

Is there a function in the C++ standard library that will not shift the elements? Like putting the back element at the removed element and pop back?

Comment: How are you defining "remove"?

Comment: what should it do instead? just skip over the elements that have been removed? Then it would be a linked list, basically. Are you looking for some hybrid between linked list and vector? (Edit: Sounds like I did not read the question thoroughly. the parentheses specify what it should do instead)

Comment: Nope, there is no such function, however the good news is that this takes about two lines of code, so this can be done faster than the time it took to write this comment. And this question.

Comment: No, there is not. It's just a two-liner though to write it yourself.

Comment: Maybe you have to consider if a std::vector is the right data structure for you in this case. Maybe a std::list would be more efficient in your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything built in, but it's trivial to do yourself.

```
std::vector<int> n = { 3, 5, 6, 7 }; // create vector
n[1] = std::move(n.back());          // move last element to removal location
n.pop_back();                        // remove unneeded element.
```

Comment: Why a swap rather than a move?

Comment: @lucidbrot The OP literally has in the Q *(put the back element at the removed element and pop back).*

Comment: @Quentin Because `swap` is implemented in terms of move.

Comment: OP's phrasing is ambiguous, I read it as asking not to do that.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for pointing that part out specifically. After super's comment I still did not see where they said that and had to use CTRL+F :p guess I skip over parentheses

Comment: But putting 5 at last element to remove it is useless though; `n[1] = std::move(n.back()); n.pop_back();` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point.  I'm doing an extra move. Code updated.

Comment: @Quentin Your comment was a little too subtle for me.  Code has been updated to do a single move instead of swap.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to shift any elements, then in C++20 you can model this with a vector of `std::optional`s and the ranges library

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto remove_element(std::vector<std::optional<T>> &v, size_t i) {
    v[i] = std::nullopt;

    return v
        | std::views::filter(&std::optional<T>::has_value)
        | std::views::transform([](auto &&o) {return *o;});
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::optional<int>> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    for (int i : remove_element(v, 3))
        cout << i << ','; // 1,2,3,5,6,

    cout << '\n';
}
```